# jQuery method throw new Error - not catched by the outside try / catch block

Tags: javascript, jquery, error-handling, javascript-objects

I'm started adding error handling to my javascript objects, which very often use jQuery.
The problem I have is that when I throw new Error from within jQuery method - it is not catched by the catch statement wrapping the jquery call - it simply throws the standard error, but does not log into the console as log message. Here's an example:

```
var MyNamespace = MyNamespace || {};

MyNamespace.Page = function() {};

MyNamespace.Page.prototype = {

    callPage : function() {

        "use strict";

        $(document).on('change', 'select', function(event) {

            event.preventDefault();
            event.stopPropagation();

            throw new Error('callPage method failed');

        });

    },

    init : function() {

        "use strict";

        try {

            this.callPage();

        } catch(errorMessage) {

            console.log('Error : ' + errorMessage);

        }

    }

};
```

When I wrap the content of the callback function with the try / catch - then it works:

```
$(document).on('change', 'select', function(event) {

    try {

        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();

        throw new Error('callPage method failed');

    } catch(errorMessage) {

        console.log('Error : ' + errorMessage);

    }

});
```

Any idea how to streamline this and why does it behave this way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the first example, the `try/catch` protects the code that *sets the event handler*, not the body of the event handler itself. That code doesn't run until the event is triggered, at which point execution has long since left the `try` block.

Consider this equivalent example:

```
try {
    var foo = function() {
        throw new Error("foo error");
    }
}
catch (error) {
}

foo();
```

You wouldn't expect the error caused by calling `foo` to be caught just because at the time `foo` was defined execution was inside the `try` block.

One solution is of course to use `try/catch` inside the body of the function that might throw, as you have shown. Another solution is to create a reusable "catching wrapper" function, perhaps like this:

```
function catchIfException(func, handler) {
    return function() {
        try {
            var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
            func.apply(this, args);
        }
        catch (error) {
            handler(error);
        }
    };
}


$(document).on('change', 'select', 
    catchIfException(
        function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            event.stopPropagation();

            throw new Error('callPage method failed');
        }, 
        function(error) {
            console.log("error: " + error);
        }
    );
);
```

Comment: I see. I'm coming from the PHP background, which processes everything synchronously - hence my misunderstanding of the topic. Thanks for the clarification - do you think that by creating error handling function that executes callback function within the try / catch block would be a good alternative? What I mean is say function tryCatch(callback) { try { callback(); } catch (error) { console.log(error); } ?

Comment: @SpencerMark: It depends. It can be a good idea if the error handler is going to be reused a lot, otherwise it would be simpler and no worse to write the try/catch inline. Note that the proposed `tryCatch` needs to be a little more involved (it should preserve `this` and forward any arguments), see my `catchIfException` above.

Comment: Thanks Jon - really appreciate your help. Would I have to use handler separately or would it be ok to just log the error to the console directly from within the catch statement of the catchIfException() ? Or perhaps make a condition checking if it was specified and either use it if so - otherwise simply log?

Comment: @SpencerMark: I can't really say, as all of this is dependent on the particulars of your situation.